# What happens when we trigger the SWF Flows @Execute method multiple times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

We have a usecase where we start a workflow (by invoking @Execute method) and the we schedule a timer for a subsequent activity. Now, this triggering of workflow is based on API call which can be triggered multiple times by a client.

1. Wanted to know how SWF flow handled the multiple invocations of @Execute method.
2. Does it create multiple executions ?
3. or would there be multiple timer clocks scheduled for same workflow execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWF allows only one open workflow execution per ID. So if the workflow is still running calling the Execute method again is going to return `WorkflowExecutionAlreadyStartedFault`.

Note that if a workflow is completed the new workflow is going to start even for the same ID.

The [temporal.io](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal) which is an open source version of SWF has an additional [WorkflowIdReusePolicy](https://github.com/temporalio/api/blob/ff5e03eb3b7315c3470e91338c7fe97b2619cfc6/temporal/api/workflowservice/v1/request_response.proto#L147) which specifies what should be done if there are already completed workflows.